# Possibilities of implementing a git server

Tags: git, version-control, github, versioning

I am following this: [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) tutorial to learn how to correctly set branches for my projects.

Doubts of where to create the repositories and branches, which of the following is a good solution:

- Use my production server as a git server for all my projects to set the repositories and branches and pull everything/updates from there
- Setup a home server to the same us the above

What other alternatives are possible?

Edit:

This is meant for Linux

Comment: please ask the second question in another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git is a distributed versioning system. That means all repositories are the same. There is no server and no client. There are repositories that are standalone and happy by themselves or with others. If you like  a backup use a second place to store a repository on a nother computer, on github, bitbucket or wherever. All you do is share your local stuff with the remote repository that has its own life and does perfectly well without you.

Comment: By server I mean a place where to create the repositories and be online always so everybody else can pull data

Comment: Then Github is the obvious choice or you start your own online repo service but that is quite pointless if it's public and github is free.

Comment: No, my main repositories are private (clients and personal) so that's why I was saying the server term. I already user github for public

Comment: oh, by everybody I understood public. My fault. You can easily set up some kind of repo server. Good luck!

Comment: your missing the point @three, I need to know where is better to deploy that server.

Comment: you could use openshift and run one of those git repo servers that run on Java, Ruby or php. You will need to do some research but that's a simple way of running a repo on a server.

Comment: you are still missing the point :D, where is a better idea to do it, on my production server or on a home server?

Comment: There are "servers" but usually "servers" host "bare" repositories and they only send / receive commits. All manipulations of history are done locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IIS, you may try **GitAspx**, which does not requires git to be installed on the server. The original one can create repositories on the web.
The forked ones in GitHub can even view tree / file content.

Comment: Note that Git Smart http protocol requires HTTP 1.1 chunked transfer encoding. Make sure your web server well support this. ASP.NET development server / xsp (mono) do not.

Comment: Nop, I use LAMP and rarely WAMP